# Can you make inheritance skip a generation?

Tags: html, css

Just wondering, can I make CSS inheritance skip a generation?
For example if I had this code:

Code:

```css
.grandfather {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.parent {
  background-color: #333;
}

.child {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class='grandfather'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
```

Is there a way for the inherit command to take the background-color from the grandfather and completely ignore the parent? Or would i need to use a variable for that?

Comment: Not possible, but you can introduce a custom property `:root { --color: #fff }` and have both `.grandfather` and `.child` use that as `background-color: var(--color)`. More and more developers are turning to *CSS custom properties* for all kinds of variable definitions. You might want to dive in to the subject....

Comment: better tell us what is you end goal, I am sure that you don't need to have this logic for what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, you cannot. The `inherit` property always takes its value from its parent.

You can read more here: [CSS inherit property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

It touches on this issue with a specific note:

> Note: Inheritance is always from the parent element in the document
> tree, even when the parent element is not the containing block.

The simple solution is to have a class in the color you wish to use e.g. `.blue {background: blue;}` and add that into the HTML or use CSS custom properties (CSS variables) to effectively do that too.